# Windows batch file If/Else Start syntax?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, syntax

I need to make a Windows batch file that will:

- 1.- Check a directory name and "If" it exists,
     a.- Run a specified *.exe from a different directory.
- 2.- Or "Else"
     a.- Rename a directory and also
     b.- Rename another directory - then
     c.- Run a *.exe from the created directory.

Question is: I'm stuck on the correct syntax ( I suppose) on creating this batch file. This is what I have, (maybe a nested if/Else would be better?) someone please enlighten me... Thanks.

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "C:\Test\Dir1" (
START "C:\Test\Dir\Test.exe"
) ELSE ( ren "C:\Test\Dir" "C:\Test\Dir1"
         ren "C:\Test\Dir2" "C:\Test\Dir"
         START "C:\Test\Dir\Test.exe"
)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing? The code looks OK to me, except the TRUE block uses START, and the FALSE block doesn't. That seems odd.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the START that was missing in the False statement, but.. it will NOT run the Test.exe in either the TRUE or the FALSE statements. I've manually changed the Dir1 or Dir2 to make each one work and will only leave me a command prompt with: C:\Test>_
The Test.exe file runs well manually. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: EDIT - I rolled the question back to previous form with path in REN target so that the accepted answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `ren` with a target name including a path or drive.

try

```
ren "C:\Test\Dir2" "Dir"
```

`start` has odd syntax - 'though it seems to not be the problem in this case. The first "quoted argument" string becomes the window title and can be routinely disregarded by the executable. Try 
routinely using

```
start "window title that can be empty if you like" "executablename" argument list
```

Even if this arguably doesn't comply exactly with the documented behaviour.

(and simplifying problems to a generality can obscure the real cause, too)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did rewrite your accurate observation yet it still does not run the Test.exe. It still only leaves the command prompt with: C:\Test>_  (which is the location where I have the batch file, if I change the location of the batch file to C:\  this is where the command prompt window will end up). 
I'm not sure I understood you about the START syntax. How would it find the correct location of the file to execute since the names of the folders will be changing? Could you be so kind as to post an example using what I posted? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dbenham and Magoo. Your responses made a world of difference on something that seems quite simple. It is now working as all the changes you both mentioned help. The final "nail in the coffin" was understanding the syntax for the START parameters. Understanding that the first parameter has double quotes and it uses that as the optional TITLE for the new window, ssoooo giving it an empty double quote ( "" ) gives it an empty title before the name of the program to fake it out. And Voila...

Thank you guys sssooo much. Final Working batch file.

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "C:\Test\Dir1" (
START "" "C:\Test\Dir\Test.exe"
) ELSE ( ren "C:\Test\Dir" "Dir1"
         ren "C:\Test\Dir2" "Dir"
         START "" "C:\Test\Dir\Test.exe"
)
```